# Is there an easy way to french trim a rack of lamb?

Tags: lamb, butchering

I had to be part of a lot of french trimming of racks of lamb at the weekend, and it seemed to take a long time, so it got me wondering, is there an easy way to do this? Some preferred tool?

Comment: It's annoyingly tedious. I always have my butcher do it. My time is worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alton Brown [demonstrates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfcbueO7bBE) using a piece of string to scrape the bone clean.  First he cuts and trims the bulk of the meat down to where he wants it.  Then, he uses a string tied to a garage door handle (very cheap at any hardware store).  Loop it around the bone a couple of times and pull, and it cleans it right up.

Comment: bah, can't see that video in the uk...  looks like a good technique though

Comment: You could likely use anything as a handle ... even a sturdy stick would work.

Comment: I would imagine that he uses the door handle since it is conveniently shaped for the human hand, doesn't have any sharp or rough edges on the hand grip, and is slightly less likely to fracture under heavy load.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen it done but with a knife. Cut the meat down to where you want it, and then scrape, scrape, scrape. I've seen people do it with all kinds of knives, but I like a nice thin boning knife.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest I've seen with minimal scraping and a little clever trick with a tea towel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnGKsjCiFOg

I should apply this when I'm trimming those racks...